# Change attribute to final

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, attributes, final

I want to initialize an attribute inherited by a subclass as a final. However, when I access the attribute, it seems to **change**, thus I suppose, that I have created another final attribute. Is it possible to make an attribute mentioned in a superclass a final attribute without creating another attribute?

Simplified code:

```
public abstract Superobj {
protected boolean attribute = false;
protected String condition; //A condition to be checked in a subclass
protected String[] collection; //Stores strings
protected int howmany= 0;


public Superobj(int i){
this.collection = new String[i];}

public void insert(String s){
this.collection[howmany] = s;
howmany++;
if (s == condition) {attribute = true;}}
```

I use another object of the another class to pass arguments to the insert method. The constructor in a subclass initializes the condition:

```
public Subclass extends Superclass{
public Sublclass(int i){
super(i);
this.condition = "cond";}}
```

However, in one subclass I don't want to change the attribute - no matter what is inserted to the table. I want to make it final, forever false, for example. I have tried:

```
public FinalSubclass extends Superclass {
protected final boolean condition = false; 
...
```

However, when I checked the value of this.attribute, it changes depending on the value of the passed argument - as if there have been created another this.attribute, opposite to the inherited ones. I cannot add to the subclass' constructor something like:

```
final this.attribute = false;
```

Is there any way to change an inherited attribute to final? Would there be an Exception, if one passes something that matches the condition and the inherited method would try to change the attribute?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This seems like an XY problem. Anyway, if this were possible, consider what would happen if you changed a variable to `final` but then called a superclass method that changed it.

Comment: Can I check whether an attribute is final in insert method, something like: `if(s == attribute && (s != final) {this.attribute = true;}` but in a way that will work? I am creating a project which requires _immutable_ attributes in some subclasses, but it I wanted to include insert methid in a Superclass

Comment: That it's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386992).

Comment: I have rewritten the bottom question. I am not concerned that this is an XY problem. I have only presented the way of thinking. If I hadn't written anything to clarify my question, it would be probably misunderstand.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) reassignment of final variables leads to *compile-time error*. Consequently you cannot "choose" variable to be or not to be `final` at *runtime*.

However, you seem to have no need in such feature.

If I understand your purpose right (I assume `Superclass` to be subtype of `Superobj`), you want to change `attribute` value on insertion always in `Superobj` (and its subclasses), except for insertion in `FinalSublcass`. So you can just override `insert` method in `FinalSublcass` in a way:

```
@Override
public void insert(String s){
    this.collection[howmany] = s;
    howmany++;
}
```

If you want `attribute` to never changed in `FinalSubclass` (not only by insertion) you can make the field private in `Superobj` and create `protected setAttribute(String attribute)` setter, which should be overridden in `Subclass` somehow like:

```
@Override
protected setAttribute(String attribute) {
    // do nothing or throw exception
}
```

But I wouldn't recommend it because of Liskov substitution principle violation (from my point of view)